# Crawling facebook store pages

Tags: facebook, vba, url, get, web-crawler

I need to check automatically thousands of possible websites, using VBA, if possible. Let me give you an example:

Say, I have these 2 columns in Excel:

```
x -  A  -                        B                     - 
1 - ID1 - https://www.facebook.com/pg/ID1/about/
2 - ID2 - https://www.facebook.com/pg/ID2/about/
3 - ID3 - https://www.facebook.com/pg/ID3/about/
4 - ID4 - https://www.facebook.com/pg/ID4/about/
```

ID1~ID4 are basically POSSIBLE Facebook store web pages, like this one, for example:
https://www.facebook.com/pg/universoimportadosoficial/about/

What I need is

a) Check if the FB page exists, i.e. not returning this: https://www.facebook.com/pg/asdsdsadadasdasad/about/

b) If it exists, using code try to extract some information from the store, such as opening hours, address, telephone and/or e-mail.

I don't think there's nothing wrong with what I'm asking, since all this information is readily available, since those pages are actually public.

Comment: `I don't think there's nothing wrong with what I'm asking` - there's no harm in asking. But scraping ethically does require a few extra considerations. Ensure you check the `robots.txt` file so you do not scrape files that the server owner does not wish you to. If you scrape more than one page from the same server, put a couple of seconds delay between each one. Declare your User Agent honestly and put a contact page in there for your robot, so server operators can get in touch with you if they wish.

Comment: Personally, I would not do this in VBA, since the libraries to do it are not likely to be available in that language. Do it in a modern language with a flourishing ecosystem: PHP, Node, Python, Ruby, Java, etc. Then get that system to output data into something your Excel spreadsheet can easily consume in a small amount of code. Related point: don't build an application inside office applications - they are often unmaintainable.

Comment: Thanks a lot Halfer, for the edits and for the replies. Although I do have knowledge on Java, It's just that I was already using VBA for filtering and changing the hundreds of thousands of data in Excel. I didn't think I'd need to mix languages, but it's no big deal, really. Would it be advisable to use Facebook APIs (if there are any that would help in this matter).

Comment: Oh right, apologies, I didn't see the URLs are all Facebook - I got distracted by the `web-crawler` tag. That's a different matter - in that case I believe you _must_ use the API. I haven't used it myself, but I hear that Facebook consider it a violation of their terms of use to scrape their content manually. Whilst I do not have a lot of sympathy with Facebook Megacorp, some of that will be motivated by wanting to protect people's private data (I appreciate that does not apply to your use case).

Comment: Scraping Facebook is not allowed according our Scraping policy. I assume you read it?

Comment: Thanks for being such a prick. Did you even bother reading my OP? Basically I need to know whether the page exists or not, and if so get the telephone or e-mail from the Store. It's a freaking STORE, which would love to have their addresses/telephones available to as many people as possible. It's completely not like I wish to get people photos or the such. there's nothing on robots.txt that disallows this so, if you can't collaborate, then don't come with "I assume you read it?" talk.  Just because you're an admin/frequent poster doesn't entitle you to mistreat one genuinely asking for help.